# KeyboardAvoidingView not working react-native

Tags: react-native, layout, keyboard

Im trying to use KeyboardAvoidingView, but i got no result with them.

styled view with styled components:

```
export const Container = styled.View({
  backgroundColor: primary,
  flex: 1,
  alignItems: 'center',
});

export const ImageView = styled.View({
  marginTop: 16,
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
});

export const InputView = styled.View({
  width: '100%',
  marginTop: 16,
});

export const TextView = styled.View({
  marginLeft: 42,
  marginRight: 42,
  marginTop: 22,
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
});

export const BottomView = styled.View({
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  alignItems: 'center',
  width: '100%',
});
```

And here is my layout. I set behavior = padding trying to solve my problem, but not works.

```
 <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Container>
        {load && <Loading />}

        <TextView>
          <Text value={diaryStrings.title} isModalMessage />
        </TextView>
        <TextView>
          <Text value={diaryStrings.hintMessage} isModalMessage />
        </TextView>
        <TextView>
          <Text value={diaryStrings.tipMessage} isModalMessage />
        </TextView>

        <ImageView>
          <ImageSvg name={'calendar'} />
        </ImageView>
        <InputView>
          <Input
            placeholder={diaryStrings.diaryName}
            placeholderTextColor={tertiary}
            maxLength={20}
            iconName="book"
            onChangeText={text => {
              setDiaryNameError('');
              setDiaryName(text);
            }}
            maskType="nomask"
            error={diaryNameError}
            value={diaryName}
          />
          <Input
            placeholder={diaryStrings.initialDate}
            placeholderTextColor={tertiary}
            maxLength={10}
            iconName="date-range"
            onChangeText={text => {
              setDiaryInitDateError('');
              setDiaryInitDate(text);
            }}
            maskType="datetime"
            error={diaryInitDateError}
            value={diaryInitDate}
          />
        </InputView>

        <BottomView>
          <Button
            title={'next'}
            hasBackgroundColor={true}
            onPress={async () => {
              setLoad(true);
              await validateForm();
              setLoad(false);
            }}
          />
          <Button
            title="Cancel"
            onPress={() => {
              navigation.navigate('Home');
            }}
          />
        </BottomView>
      </Container>
```

i think im using some property that invalidates KeyboardAvoindView. I dont wanna use an ScrollView, its possible solve this? Any one can help?

Answer (score -1):

I've struggled to get `KeyboardAvoidingView` working properly too, what worked for me was using these props for `KeyboardAvoidingView` and wrapping content in `ScrollView`:

```
    <KeyboardAvoidingView enabled keyboardVerticalOffset={90} behavior={ Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : false } style={{ flex: 1 }} >
        <ScrollView>

            {all content here}
       
         </ScrollView>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Also I had to use `TextInput` from `react-native` which needed to have `scrollEnabled={false}` prop

Comment: yeah, with scrollView i can do it work. But, i think that have any solution without using scroll. my layout has just 2 fields. I saw some examples without scroll working, but i cant do it work here. Thanks!